# Sports bars in Xi'an China

Tags: china, nightlife, sports-events, xian

Can you give the name of a sports bar or two in Xi'an, China, that would be showing popular international sports games (NBA, EPL, Champions League, Six Nations)? I have searched using Google and posted in a few sports threads but haven't found a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Belgian beer bar inside the southern wall, I would think, would be one.

http://belgian-bar-xian.com/

Answer (score 3):

Old Henry's Bar had English Premier League soccer on when I visited on Sunday night. http://www.lonelyplanet.com/china/shaanxi-shanxi/xian/entertainment-nightlife/bars-pubs/old-henrys-bar